# Visual Studio Administrator mode in Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-10, administrator

Not really sure of my exact question, but here is the situation:

I have an application (WinForms, C# .Net) that I am developing in Visual Studio 2012. It does a lot of things but the important bit is that it needs to read files from a certain location.

In this case, the location of the files is on a server and my machine has a mapped network drive setup for accessing the files. I can manually navigate to the files with Windows Explorer fine.

I have the following line in my code which is highlighting the issue:

```
System.IO.File.Exists("X:\\A Folder\\a_file.txt");
```

And that file does exist in that location. However this is where the problem occurs: if I build the solution and run the .exe directly from the "bin" folder (double-click). The code is fine, and it finds the file. But if I run it with visual studio then I get a "file not found" exception.

I am putting this down to the fact that Visual Studio is running in "Administrator" mode (I forget why I needed this, but I do). Now this makes sense if you consider that the "administrator" account does not have the "X:\" drive mapped. However, this has never been a problem until I upgraded to Windows 10 last week.

**So my question is**:

Does Visual Studio Administrator mode work differently in Windows 10? In this case, does it handle mapped network drives differently?

It's worth noting I upgraded from Windows 7, so I cannot confirm if this issue is also present in 8 and 8.1 or not.

And before anyone asks, let's just say it *has* to be a mapped drive. No UNC paths allowed!

Comment: Maybe it's not related to your question, but Windows 10 in not in Supported System list of VS 2012 Update 5. See http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48708. You may encounter other problems in future.

Comment: @qxg: Look's like I'm still on Update 4 at the minute, so I may move to 5 and see if it makes a difference...

Comment: ...no difference on Update 5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I have found a solution/workaround. Kind of seems like a wasted bounty now, so if someone has other suggestions that are better then please post and I will review them and award as applicable. Or even if somebody can make a more detailed version of my solution then I will award that one.

---

The issue is probably not specific to Visual Studio, but would occur with any application running with elevated privileges. Anyway, the solution I found is to add a registry key that enables the same shared drives to be accessible when running in administrator mode.

The registry key location is:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Policies/System

And the key to add is called:

> EnableLinkedConnections

And should be created as a `DWORD` with a value of `1` (`0x00000001`)

I checked with the machines running Windows 7 and they do NOT have this key, yet they still work fine. So I expect this isn't the only solution, but it does seem to work (no side effects noted yet). I would assume that Windows 10 has a specific setting somewhere that by default prevents mapped drives from automatically being available with "run as administrator".

For reference, I found [this information here](http://www.winability.com/how-to-make-elevated-programs-recognize-network-drives/).

In fact, [here is a more "official" recommendation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844140(v=ws.10).aspx) for using this reg key.

Comment: for this a hot fix available .I'm not sure whether this is another way rather than doing it manually .here is the [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2878604)

Answer (score 2):

This is unlikely to have anything to do with Windows 10, just with the configuration of your machine.  What you describe is normal and covered by [this KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3035277).  Nothing I can check for myself so just try the recommended workarounds, follow up at superuser.com if necessary.

Comment: I tried the first method (it was already set to "Prompt for consent for non-windows binaries", but I also tried as suggest to "Prompt for consent"), that didn't help. I don't want to try the .bat method as even if it does work I don't want it as a solution. I am the only developer with Windows 10, and I am the only developer with the problem (So I doubt it's a domain group policy issue). This problem never occurred prior to upgrade to Windows 10. When the IT guys are back in the office I will go through it with them to see if I can identify this as being a GP issue, but I am not convinced

Comment: Hmm, so that EnableLinkedConnections registry key mentioned in the article wasn't helpful to you at all?  Bummer..

Comment: Didn't even see that, maybe they should move that to the "Workaround" section where they put the other suggestions for fixing the issue. I have gave you the bounty because it expires in a couple of minutes (and I feel bad for missing the reg edit bit), but I don't particularly rate this as a decent answer... it's basically a "link only" solution

Comment: Well, thanks for the reminder that I suck.  Next time consider just editing the follow-up into the post so it can stop sucking.

Answer (score 0):

Different users/system tasks maybe running.  As such, you have the X drive mapped, but others do not.  You could do the drive mapping on additional users on your Windows installation as well.  As you stated, this should not be a Windows 10 only issue, but also Windows 7+ and elevated privileges.

Maybe you could use a configured parameter for the X: path and load at runtime, or even try using UNC paths which will resolve at runtime and not need the drive to be mapped.

```
\\ServerNameOrIP\A Folder\a_file.txt.
```

In the code, you would need:

```
System.IO.File.Exists("\\\\ServerName\\A Folder\\a_file.txt");
```